# pyTelegramBotAPI disable link preview

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

Currently writing my first bot using [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). I want to disable [link previews](https://telegram.org/blog/link-preview) on certain messages. How do I do this?

Comment: Ostone0's answer is fine, just wanted to mention you can also use the disable_web_page_preview=True on the reply_text method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks like there is an `disable_web_page_preview` parameter on the `sendMessage` method.

```py
tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
tb.send_message(123456, "Hi <link>", disable_web_page_preview=True)
```

[Original code](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/fefb9d45558b6885279225621e79b8dac63a5cb3/telebot/apihelper.py#L123);

```py
def send_message(token, chat_id, text, disable_web_page_preview=None, reply_to_message_id=None, reply_markup=None,
                 parse_mode=None, disable_notification=None):
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `link_preview`/`disable_web_page_preview` parameter.

```
client.send_message('chat_name', '[link](example.com)', parse_mode = "Markdown", link_preview=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

To me this works:

```
client.send_message(chat_name, msg, link_preview=False)
```

(Python 3.8, Telethon 1.24)