# How to Disable Web Page Preview on Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

Here is a Sample Code I use to Send a Reply to a User (A Python Telegram Bot)

```
        conf_mes = await e.reply(
            f"<a href='https://URL'>My Text</a>/n/n ..Description..",
            parse_mode="html",
            buttons=buts,
        )
```

How can I Disable Web Page Preview, When bot send Msg to User!

Comment: Please provide the library name with your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pyTelegramBotAPI disable link preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535901/pytelegrambotapi-disable-link-preview). Even if that's not the library that you're using, the parameter should be available, since is specified by the Bot API.

Answer (score 9):

add this parameter in the sendMessage method

```
disable_web_page_preview=True
```